# Issue updating number of files displayed using string.count

Tags: c#

I currently have program that merges word. doc files together via user input. Once the user chooses an input folder and output destination, the documents are combined and the total number of files merged is displayed. here is an example of the code.

```
MessageBox.Show("A total of " + sourceFiles.Count() + " documents have been merged", 
"Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
```

the program and string.count work perfectly at the moment, however the issue I have is when I update the input folder's contents or choose to the output folder to be the same as in the input folder whilst the program is running

**For Example:** If I choose the input and output folders desired and run the program successfully, the user will eventually be greeted with a message box saying "a total of X documents have been merged" once the new file has been created.

If I drag an another file into the Input folder and immediately press the 'merge' button again, the "X documents merged" total will remain the same, even though an additional file has been inserted into that folder. The program will continue to make the combined files however the string.count total doesn't recognise the newly added documents. It's as if the program doesn't update folder's total contents

Any suggestions to amend this issue? It is a small inconvenience however I would love to get it addressed.

***Updated Information:***

sourceFiles is declared as a `private string []` however its called when the user selects their desired folder using a folder browser dialog.

```
private void browseButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FolderBrowserDialog diagBrowser = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        diagBrowser.Description = "Select a folder which contains files needing combined...";

        // Default folder, altered when the user selects folder of choice 
        string selectedFolder = "";
        diagBrowser.SelectedPath = selectedFolder;

        // initial file path display
        folderPath.Text = diagBrowser.SelectedPath;

        // 'OK' button being confirmed on the popup menu
        if (DialogResult.OK == diagBrowser.ShowDialog())
        {
            // Grab the folder that was chosen
            selectedFolder = diagBrowser.SelectedPath;
            folderPath.Text = diagBrowser.SelectedPath;
            sourceFiles = Directory.GetFiles(selectedFolder, "*.doc");
        }
```

the merge command is then called, combining the sourceFiles (total number of documents in the folder), the output file name which includes a date / time and page break between the files

```
MsWord.Merge(sourceFiles, outputFileName, pageBreaker);
```

Comment: What is `sourceFiles`?

Comment: Need some more code..how is sourceFiles declared (its location etc).  Can you reset the count before displaying it?

Comment: Get the list of all the files from input folder when you press the merge button instead of getting them when user selects the input folder

Comment: `"Any suggestions to amend this issue?"` - Sure, just update the `sourceFiles` value accordingly.

Comment: i've updated the question with additional code

Comment: You're talking about `String.Count` but you're actually using `IEnumerable<T>.Count()` where T is `String`, which makes the questions somewhat confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're assuming that the string array which contains the file names will be updated when the folder's contents change. This is not the case.

You need to do `Directory.GetFiles(selectedFolder, "*.doc");` again to get the updated list of file names after you've added sfiles to the folder.

I would also follow [rashfmn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3914207/rashfmn)'s suggestion:

> Get the list of all the files from input folder when you press the merge button instead of getting them when user selects the input folder.

Because (obviously) the folder contents can change between these two points in time.

Comment: thank you for the advice. i've simply moved my "getFiles" method from the input button selection to the merge selection and is worked as intended.

Also - thank you to @rashfmn for the same suggestion. the total number outputs updates correctly no mattar how many files i drag into the folder between merge.